# Framer Motion animation not working after state change

Tags: reactjs, frontend, framer-motion

One of the components (PartSlot) in my project is rendered active or inactive based on one of the props it receives. It influences component's style, animations and behaviour, and while style and onClick tags do accept new values when prop isActive changes to `true`, the animations don't start working.

Animations work perfectly fine when PartSlots are rendered with isActive = true from the beginning, but components which were originally created with isActive = false won't work as intended.

What can I do to address this issue? Thanks in advance

Component's code:

```
function PartSlot({ isActive, iconAddress, computer, partClassName, partName, setOnClick }: PartSlotProps) {
  return {
    <motion.div 
      onClick={ isActive ? () => { setOnClick(partClassName) } : undefined }
      initial = 'tap'
      whileHover='hover'
      whileTap= {isMobile ? 'tapMobile' : 'tap'}
      style={ inactivePartSlotStyle }
    >

      <div className='IconMountLower'>
        <div className='IconMountUpper' style = { inactiveIconHolderStyle  }>
          <motion.img 
            src={iconAddress} 
            variants={ isActive ? partSlotAnimationVariants : undefined }
            transition={{
              duration: 0.08,
              ease: easeOut
            }}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* some more stuff here */}
    </motion.div>
  }
}
```

This is how components are created:

```
export const predefinedPartSlotList = (isActive: boolean, computer: Computer, onClickPartSlot: (partClassName: PartClassName) => void): Array<ReactElement> => {
    return [
        (<PartSlot key={1} isActive={isActive} iconAddress={MotherboardIcon} partClassName={PartClassName.Motherboard} computer={computer} setOnClick={onClickPartSlot} partName={"Материнская плата"}/>),
        (<PartSlot key={2} isActive={isActive} iconAddress={FanIcon} partClassName={PartClassName.Case} computer={computer} setOnClick={onClickPartSlot} partName={"Корпус"}/>)
        // More PartSlots here
        ]
};
```